# How to point to Inner Fragment within XML View

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two inner fragments in a activity.

Activity is called: `MainFragmentActivity (extends FragmentACtivity)`

Inside is this:

```
public static class FeaturedFrag extends ListFragment {
public static class TopFrag extends ListFragment {
```

How would I identify here?

```
   <fragment
        android:id="@+id/featured_frag"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.---.---.MainFragmentActvity$FeaturedFrag" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/top_items_frag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.---.---.MainFragmentActvity$TopItemFrag" />
```

Changed the XML to the recommendation, LogCat below.

```
12-05 00:27:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1243): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.---.---.MainFragmentActvit$MasterFrag: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
```

I do have a class with that name, an empty constructor and it is public.

**Full LogCat:**

```
   12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.---.---/com.---.---.master.MainFragmentActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at com.---.---.master.MainFragmentActivity.onCreate(MainFragmentActivity.java:85)
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     ... 11 more
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.---.---.MainFragmentActivity$MasterFrag: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:395)
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:363)
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:264)
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     ... 21 more
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.kickinglettce.rate_this.MainFragmentActivity$MasterFrag
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:385)
12-05 00:37:38.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     ... 24 more


Sample code from one of the inner fragments:

    public static class MasterFrag extends ListFragment {

       // fields

        public MasterFrag() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.mastercat, container, false);
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean identify? If you mean specifying the class, you do  `android:name="com.yourPackage.MainFragmentActivity$FeaturedFrag"` same for TopItemFrag.

Comment: What do you want to identify?

Comment: How to point to the inner fragment inside the XML.  I just used the above recommendation and will post LogCat for it.

Comment: Your spelling doesn't match the Name of the Activity. `MainFragmentActvit` is not the same as `MainFragmentActivity`

Comment: good call! however, I still get the error. Will post FULL logcat in a moment.

Comment: `MainFragmentActvity` is missing an I. Please double check **all** your names.

Comment: Embarrassing.. let me check again... (I found another error in spelling!) I need to slow down.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still says class is missing.  I verified all spelling.  I guess it goes back to my original question? Maybe because these are `static` classes, would that make a difference?

Comment: If they're *actually* inner classes, it shouldn't make a difference. Also, take out the contructors in the static classes, they aren't needed. So now you're working with MasterFrag or The other 2 fragments? Did you change your xml? Also, try cleaning your project.

Comment: I also noticed your package names differ `com.---.---.master.MainFragmentActivity` in one part of Log `com.kickinglettce.rate_this.MainFragmentActivity$MasterFrag` in another.

Comment: Maybe you do? Check manifests, use the search function. Proofread your code.

Comment: THAT was it!  I completely realized I reorganized everything into a sub "master" category! Thanks! (You can add that for answer!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proofread all your code. Make sure all class names are the same, are in the same packages, etc. Otherwise Android does not know where anything is.

As for your your original question, the format is `class = "package.Activity$Fragment"`